# Javascript Object Constructor & boolean variable

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, boolean

I am trying to create a JS Object constructor but want to declare one of the properties for the object with a boolean operation.  Somehow I am getting this wrong - please advise!

Thanks!
A.C.

```
function Student(gender, name, id, age, likes) {
this.gender = gender;
this.name = name;
this.id = id;
this.age = Boolean () {
    var age = x;
    if (age >= 21) {
    return "adult";
    } else {
    return "minor";
  }     
  };
this.likes = likes;
 }

window.onload = init;

function init() {
var jessica = new Student("female", "Jessica", 12, 21, ["butterflies", "flowers", "music"]);
var jessicaJSON = JSON.stringify(jessica);
console.log(jessicaJSON);

var anotherJessica = JSON.parse(jessicaJSON);
console.log(anotherJessica);

}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I am now clearer on how to use ternary conditional operator as boolean, and also on how to use the if/else statement as a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the student function fixed for you. Using ternary if statement instead of your "Boolean() {}" which really isn't valid Javascript code + boolean is either true or false, you returned "adult" or "minor" which are strings and don't really match up with Boolean type anyway.

```
function Student(gender, name, id, age, likes) {
  this.gender = gender;
  this.name = name;
  this.id = id;
  this.likes = likes;
  this.age = (age >= 21 ? "adult" : "minor");
}
```

Comment: By didn't make sense, you mean is syntactically invalid JS

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's what you need:

```
function Student(gender, name, id, age, likes) {
  this.gender = gender;
  this.name = name;
  this.id = id;
  this.age = (age >= 21) ? "adult" : "minor";
  this.likes = likes;
}

var jessica = new Student("female", "Jessica", 12, 21, ["butterflies", "flowers", "music"]);
console.log(jessica.age); //adult
```

Here I use the ternary conditional operator: `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`.

In this case the condition is `age >= 21`, the value if true is `"adult"` and the value if false is `"minor"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Student(gender, name, id, age, likes) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.age = (age >= 21) ? "adult":"minor";
    this.likes = likes;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/av5ym/1/

Answer (score 0):

Others told you what you should do, but here's an answer in the spirit of your code in case you needed more than a boolean ternary.

```
this.age = (function () {
    if (age >= 21) {
        return "adult";
    } else {
        return "minor";
    }     
}();
```